# site doesn't appear on google search in different countries

Tags: seo

i have a site, nartrade.az which is indexed by google. it appears on google search in my country(Azerbaijan). but when i search from different countries(i.e Turkey) on google, it doesn't appear on google search.

what could cause this issue? and how can i solve this issue?

Comment: You have it on a `.az` domain name, so it will only ever rank in Google in Azerbaijan.  If you want it to rank worldwide, move the site to a generic top level domain like `.com`.

Comment: but it ranks in Germany. and in Georgia also. as well as in Niger.   when it comes to Turkey, it says:  Showing results for nartrade.com
Search instead for nartrade.az